# How I can obtain the collation of a specific table in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

How I can obtain the collation of a specific table in a database? Is it possible that a table have different collation in db?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Collation at the table level is on a per column basis, so it is possible to have a collation different than the database.  If the collation is not defined at the column level, it defaults to the database collation setting.

SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       c.collation 
  FROM SYSCOLUMNS c
 WHERE [id] = OBJECT_ID('your_table_name')
```

SQL Server 2005+:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       c.collation_name
  FROM SYS.COLUMNS c
  JOIN SYS.TABLES t ON t.object_id = c.object_id
 WHERE t.name = 'your_table_name'
```

Comment: The latter case can be even simpler (no join or object ID) if you use the schema `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` instead of the schema `sys`. You will get: `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'`

Comment: Sorry, above comment applies only to SQL Server 2012 and later which obviously was not available when the answer was written, but I guess most people will be using it by now, so the comment can still be useful.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, if the database has 'CS' instead of "CI" the sql command should be written in lower case. SYS.COLUMNS -> sys.columns and SYS.TABLES -> sys.tables

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a collation for a table.

A database has a default collation (which defaults to the collation for the server).

The default collation for the database will be applied to any column you add to a table, UNLESS you explicitly specify a collation at the column level.

Comment: How I can get this column level collation?

Comment: SELECT c.name, c.collation_name  FROM SYS.COLUMNS c JOIN SYS.TABLES t ON t.object_id = c.object_id WHERE t.name = 'MyTable' and c.name = 'MyColumn'

Comment: I apologise if I have. I must be blind though because I still dont see it. Very close of course, but user asked for a particular column? I just added the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a point of note.  SSMS can show column collations when scripting out the table.  You can go into Tools-> Options.  Under SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting, there is an option to show collation when scripting out a table.  You can turn this on temporarily and script out a table to see table creation code including column collations.

Comment: It's called `Include collation` and it's under `Table and view options`. Thanks!