# Fix uppercase / lowercase letters in column names in SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql-server

Here's a little bit of context. I have a Java program which uses a SQL Server database. This Java program makes T-SQL internally: selects, updates, deletes, etc.
Every now and then there are new columns in the database structure because of new versions of the software.
On the last version, the DBA added a few columns on some of the tables. These columns where name in capital letters but the SQL statement from the Java program makes them in lower case letters.
This was tested and it's already on production environment in about more than a hundred of servers.

But there is this client, where the log registered that there is a bad SQL grammar and the selected column on the select statement doesn't exist. The problem is that it does exist. To gain some time I just simply and only for that particular client changed the column name to lower case letters and the problem got fixed.

The thing is that solution isn't efficient and I still not know why that problem came up.
The Java version of the program is jdk1.8.0_281 and the SQL server of that particularly client is SQL Server 2008 R2. (By the way, there are other clients that use the same versions without any problem at all. There are clients with all the above versions of SQL Server  working just fine)

Log details:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1=? and column2=? and column3=? and column4=? ]; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'column1'.

Does somebody know what could have happened? And how to fix it without changing the column names to lower case letters?

Comment: SQL is a case insensitive language: I would report this to Microsoft as a bug.

Comment: I took [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433149/sql-server-column-names-case-sensitivity/44086215#44086215) to mean that column names will be case sensitive if you use a case sensitive collation as the database default.

Comment: RE "without changing the column names to lower case letters". The correct fix for this is to fix this discrepancy and be consistent with casing in your application going forward and to include in your testing an instance with a CS collation

Comment: Also if on your test instance the user database and instance collations are set to different collations rather than the same collation this will mean you can catch early another possible category of errors (collation conflict errors - of which most will be resolvable by remembering to use `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` in string columns in temp tables)

Answer (score 4):

This can arise from a the database having a case-sensitive collation. A quick demo:

```sql
create database foobar collate Latin1_General_CI_AI;

use foobar;
create table dbo.myTable (ID int);
select id from myTable;
/* succeeds because the database's collation is case-insensitive */

alter database foobar collate Latin1_General_CS_AI;
select id from myTable;
/* fails because the database's collation is now case-sensitive */
```

To check what your database is using, take a look at the `sys.databases` system view in the `collation_name` column. Here's a quick query for that:

```sql
select d.name,
    d.collation_name,
    collation_description = c.[description]
from sys.databases as d
cross apply sys.fn_helpcollations() as c
where d.name = 'foobar'
    and c.name = d.collation_name;
```

NB - by omitting the predicate on database name, you can get the collation for *all* databases on the instance allowing you to address the issue holistically (if you indeed want to change the database default location).

Also NB - related to the above, changing the default database location can have application-facing implications. Test thoroughly before deploying to a production environment.

Comment: Nice - that's a trap even for experienced players.

Comment: Note that changing the database collation will not change the column collation of the existing text columns in the database.  But if your application expects a case-insensitive database and you've got a client running it with a case-sensitive database, it may have a bunch of duplicate data now.