# News Feed icon is not appearing using juicer Api

Tags: c#, sql

I have this text to get from juicer api `<p>test message ✈️</p>` when save this text in sql database so icon in this text is replace to `??` double question mark i dont know why how can i fixed this issue, because i want to display this text with in my application news feed area.
Pleae help me how can i fixed this issue.

[image]

Comment: When saving to Database check that Text/String Encoding is same (i.e. Unicode)

Comment: This is `Unicode` (UTF-16?) character. Change your DB encoding.

Comment: What is your DB settings(encoding, type etc)?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava vasily Selim i have update my question you can check that message property have showing icon.

Comment: Check the Encoding of the column where this text is going? What DB are you using? Ex: MSSQL char is not unicode use nvarchar.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava MSSQL message column type is text

Comment: @ArsalanQaiser this is not an icon. This is a single Unicode character with code of [U+2708](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2708/index.htm). This character is 2 bytes in length, so when you try to save it in UTF-8 (where 1 character = 1 byte) - you get 2 characters of 1 byte in length (`??`). So the question is: what is your DB table encoding?

Comment: @vasily.sib message column encoding is default

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304992/how-i-can-obtain-the-collation-of-a-specific-table-in-a-database) you can find how to get your column collation (encoding)

Comment: @vasily.sib this is my collation value for message column is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Comment: @ArsalanQaiser now, read [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#Supplementary_Characters) - the answer should be there.

Answer (score 1):

@PrateekShrivastava MSSQL message column type is text

Please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

**text**
Variable-length **non-Unicode** data in the code page of the server and with a maximum string length of 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). When the server code page uses double-byte characters, the storage is still 2,147,483,647 bytes. Depending on the character string, the storage size may be less than 2,147,483,647 bytes.

Change column to nvarchar(MAX) or ntext

Comment: i have changed the column type ntext it is still saving "<p>test message ??</p>" and also try on nvarchar it's not working. And check from make insert script and then run in sql directly